# Does CodeIgniter cache resources like CSS?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, caching

Each time I change something in my .CSS I can't see any change on my website.

Only after instead of typical refresh I do force refresh by

`ctrl+F5`

Why? It's like CodeIgniter is caching this css file. And maybe other files. Something like mod_deflate or mod_expires...

But in main .htaccess (main folder) I have only

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Maybe somewhere else? In other file? CodeIgniter's doing this.

Where?

Comment: maybe browser itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this add new one more line in code check it i hope your work is fine,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @AdriannoBarello if worked you can accept this users answer

Comment: But what does exactly this line do?

Comment: But what does exactly this line do? @Khetesh

Comment: You want more information click here https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html